# Regression of a timeseries delta in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, regression, linear-regression

Lets say I have a timeseries like this

```
    A   B
0   a   b
1   c   d
2   e   f 
3   g   h
```

0,1,2,3 are times,  a, c, e, g is one time series and b, d, f, h is another time series.

What i need is a regression of deltas, meaning

```
       dA     dB
0    (a-c)  (b-d)
1    (c-e)  (d-f)
2    (e-g)  (f-h)
```

I was to do regress as  `dB = X dA + Y`

Now whats the best way to do this if i have a pandas dataframe like above to start with.
Also, next I would like to do a moving window regression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pandas` and `statsmodel` work beautifully together for things like this, see this example:

```
In [16]:

import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
In [17]:

df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10,2)), columns=['A','B'])
In [18]:

df.index=pd.date_range('1/1/2014', periods=10)
In [19]:

dfd=df.diff().dropna()
In [20]:

print df
                   A         B
2014-01-01  0.455924  0.375653
2014-01-02  0.585738  0.864693
2014-01-03  0.201121  0.640144
2014-01-04  0.685951  0.256225
2014-01-05  0.203623  0.007993
2014-01-06  0.626527  0.719438
2014-01-07  0.327197  0.324088
2014-01-08  0.115016  0.635999
2014-01-09  0.660070  0.246438
2014-01-10  0.141730  0.125918

[10 rows x 2 columns]
In [21]:

print dfd
                   A         B
2014-01-02  0.129814  0.489041
2014-01-03 -0.384617 -0.224549
2014-01-04  0.484830 -0.383919
2014-01-05 -0.482328 -0.248233
2014-01-06  0.422905  0.711446
2014-01-07 -0.299330 -0.395351
2014-01-08 -0.212182  0.311911
2014-01-09  0.545054 -0.389561
2014-01-10 -0.518340 -0.120520

[9 rows x 2 columns]
In [22]:

mod1 = smf.ols('A ~ B', data=dfd).fit()
In [23]:

print mod1.summary()
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      A   R-squared:                       0.036
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                 -0.101
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                    0.2637
Date:                Fri, 18 Apr 2014   Prob (F-statistic):              0.623
Time:                        13:54:27   Log-Likelihood:                -4.5434
No. Observations:                   9   AIC:                             13.09
Df Residuals:                       7   BIC:                             13.48
Df Model:                           1                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [95.0% Conf. Int.]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept     -0.0295      0.152     -0.194      0.852        -0.389     0.330
B              0.1960      0.382      0.513      0.623        -0.707     1.099
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                        1.832   Durbin-Watson:                   3.290
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.400   Jarque-Bera (JB):                1.006
Skew:                           0.506   Prob(JB):                        0.605
Kurtosis:                       1.711   Cond. No.                         2.52
==============================================================================
```

For the 2nd question you have to provide more detail or open a separate question. There are many different kinds of sliding windows, you need to be more specific.

## Edit

The simple linear regression you just described, in case you only want to store the two coefficients, can be achieved as follows:

```
win_size=5
win_step=2
coef_ls=[]
for i in range(0,len(dfd)-win_size,2):
    coef_ls.append(smf.ols('A ~ B', data=dfd.ix[i:i+win_size]).fit().params)
pd.concat(coef_ls, axis=1).T # The resulting DataFrame of coefficients.
```

Comment: THank you for the answer. Regarding sliding window, what I need to do is - Lets say I take 100 datapoints (0 - 100) for first regression. And then i need to do 20 to 120 and then 40 to 140 and so on. And basically in each of these i want to get the coefficients. And then may be take an average of those.

Comment: See edit. But also explore the rolling window methods already provided  by `pandas`, you may find something suit your real world application better: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html